# Setting user country in dropdown

Tags: magento

I have a task that requires that I set a country for all customers who do not have a country set (this is an error caused from a previous customer import) for shipping/billing addresses. The country is now available for the default billing/shipping address.

However, on the right hand side, the country dropdown is not being populated. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to update this. Is it part of a different address that is not related to the shipping/billing address?

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/2G1s261v2a2V

This is the code that I've been using to batch update the default country.

```
$customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

foreach ($customers as $customer) {

    // get individual customer
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());

    // now get their address
    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

    $address
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ;

    $address_data = $address->getData();

    if ( !isset($address_data['country_id']) || $address_data['country_id'] == 'United States' ) {
        $address->setCountryId('US');
    }

    try {
        $address->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::log(json_encode($e->getMessage()));
    }

}
```

Comment: from your screenshot i can find for your first address (which is not your default address) you did not set the country so that you can't find the country set on the right side. Next you have set the country for the default address correctly BUT YOU DIDN'T CLICK THAT ADDRESS TO CHECK WHETHER IT HAS BEEN SET... JUST CLICK ON THAT ADDRESS ON THE LEFT SO THAT YOU CAN GET THE SAME ADDRESS ON THE RIGHT...its an illusion mate ;-)

Comment: BTW a few edits in your code let me just post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $default_country_id = "US";

   /*Loads Customer Collection*/ 
   $customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
   foreach($customers as $customer):
      $customerDetails = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
      /*Loads customer addresses*/ 
      foreach ($customerDetails->getAddresses() as $address): 
        /*If country is not set then it will set the default country to the address*/
        if(!$address->getData('country_id')){
            $address->setCountryId($default_country_id)->save();
        }
      endforeach;
   endforeach;
```